# Salesforce API: Error on ->update(), "INVALID_TYPE: Must send a concrete entity type."

Tags: php, salesforce

I've been researching this and trying many variations based off my understanding of how to update a record in an SObject, but I keep getting the following error:

> SoapFault exception: [sf:INVALID_TYPE] INVALID_TYPE: Must send a concrete entity type. in /home/public_html/soapclient/SforceBaseClient.php:509

I am able to login successfully to the page, but when I execute the code below, I am getting the error listed above.

```
    $fieldsToUpdate = array (
        "Name"=>$_POST['Name']
    );

    $sObject = new SObject();
    $sObject->Id = $_POST['prospectID']; // this is the Id of the record
    $sObject->fields = $fieldsToUpdate;
    $sObject->type = 'Prospect__c'; // this is the API name of custom object

    try {
        $response = $mySforceConnection->update($sObject);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e;
    }
```

I am using PHP Toolkit 13.0 from the Force.com developer docs, but not able to get to the bottom of this error. Also, I am using the Enterprise WSDL in sandbox mode, and have the proper wsdl xml assigned.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sObject is the base type for all other Salesforce objects that can be updated.  When using the enterprise API (SOAP), you'll need to pass instances that derive from sObject. (Lead, Contact, and Account are examples)

Here is the documentation for the [update()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_update.htm) method as well.

Comment: How would I then go about creating the table Prospect__c as an sObject? Syntax-wise.

Comment: I gave my answer based on the error message you're getting, however I should also add that I'm not too familiar with the PHP library for working with the enterprise API.  If Prospect__c is your custom object, do your bindings allow you to create new Prospect__c() instead of new sObject()?  Have you reimported the wsdl after creating this custom object?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the PHP Library for Enterprise either, and have been fumbling with their examples for PHP. I have tried `$sObject = new Prospect__c();` but that code doesn't compile at all. In the documentation, the C# example seems to insinuate that the format should be `Prospect__c sObject = new Prospect__c();`

Not having any luck with that format in PHP.

Comment: Here's another link http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_13.0_Samples.  My experience is with the enterprise API using C# as well.  After looking at some of the examples, I'm wondering if maybe you are using partner API samples instead of the enterprise API?  Hope this helps

Comment: I think I was when I first posted this. Since then, this example has also failed for the same reason:

`$sObject = new stdClass();
  $sObject->Id = $_POST['prospectID'];
  $sObject->Name = $_POST['name'];
  $sObject->type = 'Prospect__c';
 
  try {
   $response = $mySforceConnection->update($sObject);
   print_r($response);
  } catch (Exception $e) {
   echo $e->faultstring;
  }
  
  echo "<p>bottom.</p>";`

Comment: try passing the object type with the update call, like: $response = $mySforceConnection->update($sObject, 'Prospect__c');

Comment: /sigh tried that as well. It still generates the same INVALID_TYPE error.

Comment: maybe try removing this line: $sObject->type = 'Prospect__c'; I think that is for the partner API, maybe it's overriding the type that is sent in the SOAP request for the enterprise method?

Comment: I switched over to using the PartnerClient and had no problems (just as an update to this). Still no idea what was going on with the enterprise client.

Comment: @pXdty switching to partner client also solved it for me. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply an object type as the second update() argument. Also, the first argument of the update() method must be an array of objects you'd like to update:

```
$response = $mySforceConnection->update(array($object), 'Prospect__c');
```

Also, you do not need to use any object classes provided by the toolkit, a simple StdClass should work:

```
$prospect = new StdClass();
$prospect->Id = '006....';
$prospect->Name 'Foobar';
$response = $mySforceConnection->update(array($prospect), 'Prospect__c');
```

FYI, I have never found a way to update multiple object types at once, but you can update a batch of the same type of objects, hence why the first parameter needs to be an array. The Salesforce toolkit doesn't automatically account for someone passing a single object (i.e. it doesn't wrap it in an array for you). I have always used an abstraction layer between my application logic and Salesforce's SOAP toolkit, which provides conveniences like I just described.

Answer (score 0):

if your are using Partner wsdl

```
 <?php
    // SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR - folder that contains the PHP Toolkit and your WSDL
    // $USERNAME - variable that contains your Salesforce.com username (must be in the form of an email)
    // $PASSWORD - variable that contains your Salesforce.com password

    define("SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR", "../../soapclient");
    require_once (SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/SforcePartnerClient.php');
    require_once ('../userAuth.php');

    try {
      $mySforceConnection = new SforcePartnerClient();
      $mySoapClient = $mySforceConnection->createConnection(SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/partner.wsdl.xml');
      $mylogin = $mySforceConnection->login($USERNAME, $PASSWORD);

    /*--------------------------------------------------------\
    | Please manage the values for OBJECT ID from file 
    | userAuth.php
    \--------------------------------------------------------*/

      $fieldsToUpdate = array (
      'FirstName' => 'testupdate',
      'City' => 'testupdateCity',
      'Country' => 'US'
      );
      $sObject1 = new SObject();
      $sObject1->fields = $fieldsToUpdate;
      $sObject1->type = 'Lead';
      $sObject1->Id = $UPDATEOBJECTID1;

      $fieldsToUpdate = array (
      'FirstName' => 'testupdate',
      'City' => 'testupdate',
      'State' => 'testupdate',
      'Country' => 'US'
      );
      $sObject2 = new SObject();
      $sObject2->fields = $fieldsToUpdate;
      $sObject2->type = 'Lead';
      $sObject2->Id = $UPDATEOBJECTID2;
      $sObject2->fieldsToNull = array('Fax', 'Email');

      $response = $mySforceConnection->update(array ($sObject1, $sObject2));

      print_r($response);

    } catch (Exception $e) {
      print_r($mySforceConnection->getLastRequest());
      echo $e->faultstring;
    }
?>
```

else for enterprises wsdl use

```
<?php
// SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR - folder that contains the PHP Toolkit and your WSDL
// $USERNAME - variable that contains your Salesforce.com username (must be in the form of an email)
// $PASSWORD - variable that contains your Salesforce.com password

define("SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR", "../../soapclient");
require_once (SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/SforceEnterpriseClient.php');
require_once ('../userAuth.php');

try {
  $mySforceConnection = new SforceEnterpriseClient();
  $mySoapClient = $mySforceConnection->createConnection(SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/enterprise.wsdl.xml');
  $mylogin = $mySforceConnection->login($USERNAME, $PASSWORD);

/*--------------------------------------------------------\
| Please manage the values for OBJECT ID from file 
| userAuth.php
\--------------------------------------------------------*/

  $sObject1 = new stdclass();
  $sObject1->Id = $UPDATEOBJECTID1;
  $sObject1->FirstName = 'testupdate';
  $sObject1->City = 'testupdateCity';
  $sObject1->Country = 'US';

  $sObject2 = new stdclass();
  $sObject2->Id = $UPDATEOBJECTID2;
  $sObject2->FirstName = 'testupdate';
  $sObject2->City = 'testupdate';
  $sObject2->State = 'testupdate';
  $sObject2->Country = 'US';
  $sObject2->fieldsToNull = array('Fax', 'Email');

  $response = $mySforceConnection->update(array ($sObject1, $sObject2), 'Lead');

  print_r($response);

} catch (Exception $e) {
  print_r($mySforceConnection->getLastRequest());
  echo $e->faultstring;
}
?>
```

Comment: will somebody provide me the reason for voting down