# Updates through Salesforce API not committing

Tags: php, salesforce

I am trying to update a Contact using the Salesfore PartnerClient in PHP (13.1). Here is the code I am running:

```
$sObject = new sObject();
$sObject->Id = '003E000000hyhOxIAI';
$sObject->fields = array(
  'Title' => 'Test update',
  'Custom_Filed__C' => 'Foo'
);
$sObject->type = 'Contact';

// run the update
try {
  var_dump($sf->update($sObject));
} catch(Exception $e) {
  // we have an error
}
```

The above runs fine, with the following response:

```
object(stdClass)#9 (2) { ["id"]=> string(18) "003E000000hyhOxIAI" ["success"]=> bool(true) }
```

So everything looks correct, and I've ensured that the user I am connecting with has write-access. However, when looking at the target contact on Salesforce, I can see that the last update coincides with the timestamp of running the above update, but that the fields I've specified are not updated. Any pointers on what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, for anyone that faces the same issue, the solution is to pass in an array of `sObjects` - the [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10326862/357801) I had seen failed to include this detail. Looking at the [API docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_update.htm), it does look like the array is needed - just strange that the `update()` method does not indicate this in it's response.